# How to get nginx on ec2 to work with https

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-route53

This is what I have setup on AWS in a nutshell:
I have an ec2 (windows server) lets call it my WebAppInstance which hosts a .Net based web api application.

Then I have another ec2 instance (windows server) which has another instance of the same web app, lets call it WebAppInstanceStaging.

Now, in order to achieve canary deployment, I created another ec2 (ubuntu) to host nginx to redirect the request to either WebAppInstance OR WebAppInstanceStaging based on the request header.

I have put my nginx behind an elb to make use of the ssl cert I have in AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) since it cannot be directly used with an ec2. And then I created a Route 53 record set in the domain registered with AWS (*.mydomain.com).

In Route 53 I created a record set as myapp.mydomain.com.
Now when I access the http://myapp.mydomain.com I am able to access it but when I try to access http**s**://myapp.mydomain.com I am seeing error saying This site can't be reached (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED).
Below is the configuration of my nginx:

```
upstream staging {
 server myappstaging.somedomain.com:443;
}

upstream prod {
 server myapp.somedomain.com:443;
}

# map to different upstream backends based on header
map $http_x_server_select $pool {
 default "prod";
 staging "staging";
}

   server {
 listen 80;
 server_name <publicIPOfMyNginxEC2> <myapp.mydomain.com>;
 location / {
      proxy_pass https://$pool;

      #standard proxy settings
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
proxy_connect_timeout 600;
      proxy_send_timeout 600;
      proxy_read_timeout 600;
      send_timeout 600;
 }
}
```

Been more than a day trying to figure it out. What am I missing?

Comment: did you check ec2 security groups for 443 port are open @tavier

Comment: what type of connection does the LB do? http or https? if it's https, you are listening to port 80 and not443, so there you have the problem, if it's http with a header for the $scheme, you are setting x-forwarded proto to $scheme (that will always be http as it enters through port 80) and then proceed to https through a proxy_pass.

Comment: yeah I have 443 open in both elb as well as the security group. I also tried removing x-forward header